# plotly.plot will not plot all the data frames

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Im trying to plot four data frames. All the data frames have only one column and Datetime as Index. im trying to plot all these data frames in one graph. But I get plot of only two

I have tried commenting one of them But again it plots two out of three

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
plt.title("Monthly Load Prediction" ,fontsize=25)
plt.plot(predictedbyXGB, label='Proposed Model')
plt.plot(test_target, label='Actual Data')
plt.plot(predictedbynb, label='Naive Bayes')
plt.plot(predictedbylinear, label='Linear Regression')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(loc='best',fontsize=18)
plt.show()
```

[image: Results]

Comment: can you post the data as well? so that we can test it our ends also?

Comment: Hmmm...There is not!

Comment: Here is the link to the data                                                                             
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/r4j2glnj4dp6uiv/AAAWG68KkieLNBRlKrGL_dQ7a?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the data I found out that the values in different data frames were almost the same with differences less than 0..01. All the values were plotted but they are not visible because of the lie in the same places except for the values of predictedbyXGB/Proposed model.